# Self Built MacVim on OSX 10.6 doesn't open a GUI window

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, git, compile, macvim

I've noticed the [MacVim downloads page](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/releases) has stopped uploading pre-compiled snapshots for OSX 10.6 (only 10.7 is supported now, with 10.6 considered LEGACY). I'm still using 10.6 and wanted to build it myself. I used the following to do so:

```
git clone https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim.git
cd macvim
./configure --with-features=huge \
            --enable-gui=macvim \
            --enable-macvim-check=yes \
            --with-ruby-command=`rbenv which ruby` \
            --enable-rubyinterp=yes \
            --enable-pythoninterp=yes \
            --enable-perlinterp \
            --enable-cscope=yes \
            --with-python-config-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/config

make
```

It compiled without any errors, though when I open the `src/MacVim/build/Release/` and clicked the `MacVim.app` icon, nothing happened. That is, the application launched but no GUI window opened. If I download a pre-built legacy snapshot and install it, things work fine. Am I missing something, or does macvim not support 10.6 anymore? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Python path tells me you have Homebrew installed. There is a formula for MacVim; I built it properly on Snow Leopard with the command:

```
brew install macvim --with-cscope --with-lua --override-system-vim
```

The formula is currently on 7.3 snapshot 64.

On Mountain Lion, I had to follow [slightly more complicated instructions](https://superuser.com/questions/461845/how-can-i-use-the-homebrew-python-with-homebrew-macvim-on-mountain-lion).